# How to get tap location on world coordinate?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

Can we be known of where we have tapped(touched once) on a box2d world. As, `location = [self convertCoordToLayer:location];
location.x,location.y` returns screen coordinate. So is there any method to get world coordinate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on how you correlate your physical world and the graphics. Usually it's enough to divide the touch position relative to the layer by PTM_RATIO:

```
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchLocation];
    CGPoint nodePosition = [self convertToNodeSpace: touchLocation];
    b2Vec2 pos(nodePosition.x/PTM_RATIO, nodePosition.y/PTM_RATIO);
```